# undefined reference to `cv::viz::Viz3d::Viz3d(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)'

Tags: c++, opencv, cmake, 3d-reconstruction

I am working on 3D reconstruction and trying to visualize 3D points using opencv2/viz but there seems this linker error:
`undefined reference to cv::viz::Viz3d::Viz3d(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)`
(I have however obtained 3D points from triangulation)

When building OpenCV i had set `OPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH` path to `opencv_contrib/modules` in my device. Also, `/usr/include/opencv2/` has viz include files (`viz.hpp` and other headers inside viz directory). Do i have to include OpenCV extra libraries in CMakeLists.txt (I think `include_directories(${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS})` should work because `#include<opencv2/viz.hpp>` does not throw any error.)? How do i solve this error?

Comment: "undefined reference" has the usual causes. are you *linking* the module too? I don't know what cmake needs to know to make that happen. in any case, if you've linked the `core` module and such, you'll need to link the `viz` module as well (since you use it).

Comment: I have tried doing `find_library(VIZLIB viz "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_viz.so")` and then `target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ${VIZLIB})` in CMakeLists.txt of the project but problem still remains. How do i link the `viz` module?